# Loading 40GB twitter JSON TAR file from archive.org and load into PostgreSQL

Tags: python, performance, json, postgresql

I wrote the script below to load data obtained from the twitter JSON archive on archive.org into a PostgreSQL database.

I'm looking for optimizations in the code. It currently runs at ~1.7 seconds per file (of 50,000 files), or loads 3 million rows in an hour.

Would I be looking at multithreading? The first run took approximately 12 hours (see profiler below).

Also, my setup is as follows:

- Python 2.7, 32-bit, Windows 8
- PostgreSQL running on an external USB 3.0 hard drive
- TAR files are on that same USB hard drive

```
"""
Read the output of an extracted TAR twitter archive from:
https://archive.org/details/twitterstream
"""
import bz2
import datetime
import json
import os
import profile
import psycopg2
from pprint import pprint


with open("postgresConnecString.txt", 'r') as f:
    DB_CONNECTIONSTRING = f.readline()

conn = psycopg2.connect(DB_CONNECTIONSTRING)
CACHE_DIR = "H:/Twitter datastream/PYTHONCACHE"

def load_bz2_json(filename):
    """ Takes a bz2 filename, returns the tweets as a list of tweet dictionaries"""
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        s = f.read()
        lines = bz2.decompress(s).split("\n")
    tweets = []
    for line in lines:
        try:
            if line == "":
                num_lines -= 1
                continue
            tweets.append(json.loads(line))
        except: # I'm kind of lenient as I have millions of tweets, most errors were due to encoding or so)
            continue
    return tweets


def load_tweet(tweet, tweets_saved):
    """Takes a tweet (dictionary) and upserts its contents to a PostgreSQL database"""
    try:
        tweet_id = tweet['id']
        tweet_text = tweet['text']
        tweet_locale = tweet['lang']
        created_at = tweet['created_at']
    except KeyError:
        return tweets_saved

    data = {'tweet_id': tweet_id,
            'tweet_text': tweet_text,
            'tweet_locale': tweet_locale,
            'created_at_str': created_at,
            'date_loaded': datetime.datetime.now(),
            'tweet_json': json.dumps(tweet)}
    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO tweets (tweet_id, tweet_text, tweet_locale, created_at_str, date_loaded, tweet_json)
                       VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);""", (data['tweet_id'], data['tweet_text'], data['tweet_locale'],
                                                             data['created_at_str'], data['date_loaded'], data['tweet_json']))
    except: # Kind of lenient for errors, here again.
        return tweets_saved
    finally:
        cur.close()
    tweets_saved += 1
    return tweets_saved


def handle_file(filename, retry=False):
    """Takes a filename, loads all tweets into a PostgreSQL database"""
    tweets = load_bz2_json(filename)
    tweets_saved = 0
    for tweet in tweets:
        tweets_saved = load_tweet(tweet, tweets_saved)  # Extracts proper items and places them in database
    conn.commit()
    return True

def main():
    files_processed = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(CACHE_DIR):
        for file in files:
            files_processed +=1
            filename = os.path.join(root, file)
            #print(file)
            print('Starting work on file ' + str(files_processed) + '): ' + filename)
            handle_file(filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pprint('Starting work!')
    profile.run('main()')
    conn.close()
else:  # If running interactively in interpreter (Pycharm):
    filename = r"H:\Twitter datastream\PYTHONCACHE\2013\01\01\00\00.json.bz2"
```

I retried the profiler with less files (1,000); the following is the output:

```
ncalls  lineno(function)tottime %oftime filename             
2870689 0(execute)              916,953 40,77%               
1000    0(decompress)           511,18  22,73%               
3245379 372(raw_decode)         231,57  10,30%   decoder.py  
2870689 212(iterencode)         123,231 5,48%    encoder.py  
1000    0(read)                 74,577  3,32%                
1000    0(commit)               66,478  2,96%                
1000    0(open)                 53,977  2,40%                
3245379 39(load_tweet)          43,261  1,92%    pyTwitter.py
1098    0(_isdir)               31,037  1,38%                
3245379 361(decode)             21,016  0,93%    decoder.py  
2870690 0(join)                 20,995  0,93%                
2870689 186(encode)             19,343  0,86%    encoder.py  
2870689 0(cursor)               18,513  0,82%                
2870689 193(dumps)              16,998  0,76%    __init__.py 
2870689 0(now)                  16,072  0,71%                
1       77(main)                14,142  0,63%    pyTwitter.py
1000    68(handle_file)         11,296  0,50%    pyTwitter.py
1000    21(load_bz2_json)       9,872   0,44%    pyTwitter.py
6490758 0(match)                8,277   0,37%
```

My first performance edit:

- Create a cursor once per file
- conn.commit() once per 10 files.
- Write one insert statement per file (following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query/10147451#10147451)

This is the profiler result for a full run on one extracted TAR file. The full code is available at [github](https://github.com/MVersteeg/Twitter-Archive-Loader/blob/master/pyTwitter.py)

```
#    ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
#     39377 17316.266    0.440 17316.266    0.440 :0(decompress)
# 130997418 9288.108    0.000 9288.108    0.000 decoder.py:372(raw_decode)
#     39214 5283.592    0.135 5283.592    0.135 :0(execute)
#  46834100 1622.474    0.000 1622.474    0.000 encoder.py:212(iterencode)
#  46834100  904.214    0.000  904.216    0.000 :0(mogrify)
# 130997418  854.491    0.000 10779.594    0.000 decoder.py:361(decode)
#     39377  725.356    0.018  725.356    0.018 :0(open)
#     39377  600.551    0.015  600.551    0.015 :0(read)
#         1  560.083  560.083 41120.377 41120.377 pyTwitter.py:78(main)
# 130997418  546.896    0.000 3179.022    0.000 pyTwitter.py:39(load_tweet)
# 46873315/46873314  407.746    0.000 1384.412    0.000 :0(join)
#     39377  400.072    0.010 40491.833    1.028 pyTwitter.py:62(handle_file)
#     39377  399.955    0.010 30489.249    0.774 pyTwitter.py:21(load_bz2_json)
# 261994836  338.315    0.000  338.315    0.000 :0(match)
# 130997418  308.528    0.000 11088.122    0.000 __init__.py:293(loads)
#  46834100  261.071    0.000 2277.501    0.000 encoder.py:186(encode)
#     39215  256.085    0.007  256.085    0.007 :0(split)
#  46834100  227.774    0.000 2505.275    0.000 __init__.py:193(dumps)
# 261994836  208.695    0.000  208.695    0.000 :0(end)
# 177871780  165.239    0.000  165.239    0.000 :0(append)
#  46834100  126.850    0.000  126.850    0.000 :0(now)
# 131197028   90.289    0.000   90.289    0.000 :0(len)
#  93668202   87.131    0.000   87.131    0.000 :0(isinstance)
#  46873314   72.450    0.000  976.665    0.000 pyTwitter.py:74(<genexpr>)
#       723   27.384    0.038   27.384    0.038 :0(listdir)
#     40099   25.166    0.001   25.166    0.001 :0(_isdir)
#       392   12.197    0.031   12.197    0.031 :0(commit)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12206600/398670, http://stackoverflow.com/q/758945/398670 . Your current code does practically everything it can to be *slower*.

Comment: Thank you for the links, very enlightening. Could you perhaps elaborate a bit on what parts from the code you would optimize? The postgresql side seems straightforward, but regarding the python code: should I do one commit all the way at the end? Thanks again, please note that I'm still starting out (fourth week of python).

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Comment: If you're still looking at this you could also try to see if [pgloader](http://pgloader.com/howto/quickstart.html) is usable for your input.

Comment: And also try `ujson` for JSON handling, it's a drop-in replacement for the `json` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Improving throughput

If you want to get the best possible throughput, you need to decompose this into a few processes.

The decompression can be handled with  `bzcat`, available for Windows as part of the GnuWin tools.

psycopg2's `execute` sends commands to the database synchronously and one-at-a-time. The `executemany` method also issues commands synchronously and one-at-a-time. Rather than attempt to get around this in Python, you could instead use PostgreSQL's console-based tool, [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html).

The approach would be to move your JSON-parsing and record generating code into a standalone Python script that would read the uncompressed JSON records from `stdin` and write CSV data to `stdout` which would be passed to the psql process that would read it as part of a `\copy` (refer to the documentation for psql and the  command). The transform script will look something like:

```
import csv

def json_to_tuple(tweet):
    return (tweet['id'],
            tweet['text'],
            tweet.get('lang','\\N'), # \N is NULL placeholder for PSQL COPY
            tweet['created_at'],
            datetime.datetime.now(), # FIXME: Format for PSQL COPY
            json.dumps(tweet)
           )

tweets = (tweet for tweet in map(json.loads, sys.stdin) if 'id' in tweet)
csvwriter = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
csvwriter.writerows(map(json_to_tuple, tweets))
```

You would then modify your driver script to walk through all of the compressed data files and pass them through the pipeline (refer to `Popen` in the subprocess module).

You could also process the files directly from the .tar file:

```
tar xvfO archiveteam-twitter-stream-2014-02.tar --wildcards '*.bz2' | bzcat | python3 transform.py | psql -1f copy.sql
```

## Encoding problems

It's not clear which version of Python you are using but I suspect that calling `.split("\n")` is the source of the encoding errors. In Python 3.4.0, that raises a "TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API" but it's possible in other versions you could end up with an object with the wrong encoding. You should not be encountering any errors with the source files.

Your load_bz2_json function could be vastly simplified to:

```
def load_bz2_json(filename):
    with bz2.BZ2File(filename,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            tweet = json.loads(line)
            yield tweet
```

If the above code still produces encoding errors, comment below.

Comment: Thank you very much! I added http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900330/loading-a-tar-file-and-extracting-it-to-sdout-with-bzcat in order to illustrate where it's currently generating errors.

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I know of to improve throughput when dealing with a large quantity of inserts, is to turn off autocommit, until you are done spooling up all the inserts, and then commit at the end.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/populate.html

Of course, as was suggested, using the command line tools is a good way, since that's built to do this sort of thing.  When working on performance concerns for FPDB (free poker database), any operation that looked like it would require more than a handful of inserts, was done with autocommit off.  Performance from that was immeasurably different from shelling out to the command line tool. (although we were usually working with "hundreds" not "millions" of inserts there)

Another thing would be re-working it to suck up a lot more memory, at the expense of it's straight-forwardness.  Decompressing the file, then reading as much of it in as possible, then parsing it, will quite likely show several gains, as well.  These are all techniques that we used in FPDB to improve performance when dealing with perhaps hundreds of datafiles containing any number of potential inserts.

And the last one that I recall, was moving to a multi-threaded model.  The multi-threaded model can be very tricky -- unless you're working on solid state disks, you can quickly give up all or most of your performance improvements if you start throwing in disk reads that require seeks all over the disk.  If I remember correctly, many people had discovered that it was actually faster in many cases to work only on very small subsets of the data, but do it in several threads, and let the system and hardware caches do what they are good at.

There are many many ways to restructure this, being this straight-forward makes good, readable code, but is rarely the most efficient way to go when dealing with very large datasets.